# MySQL Primary Key with non unique data in fields

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, composite-primary-key

What is the best way to generate a primary key in the following table structure?  Using MySQL 5.6 community.

```
PosDateTime varchar(24)
Model varchar(5)
Hour Int(11)
Lat double
Lon double
Wind Int(11)
Pres Int(11)
```

There will be many instances of each of these fields containing the same value throughout the table, but there will not be a record that is exactly identical (at least one field will be different).  So if I'm not mistaken, I can't use any of these fields as a Primary Key because of duplicates, right??

This table will have up to about 50,000 records.
Currently, before I insert into the table, I check to see if the record already exists, then do the insert if it's not there, it takes a little longer because I do not have a primary key setup.
I'll also need to search on the table to get values.

Should I use a composite primary key using all fields?

This table will not relate to other tables in any way.
Thanks for your input.  Bryan

Comment: The definition of a primary key is that it MUST be unique so you can identify a given row. If the values are not unique they can't be a primary key. Now you can have a primary key that consists of more than one column. That is known as a composite key. Also, you should only tag the relevant DBMS that you are using. sql server <> mysql.

Comment: @AlmaDo  I did see that post before submitting my question, but to me it's talking about 2 tables and how they relate to each other.  I just have a single table.  I'm new at this, so maybe there is something with the other post I'm not getting.  So, is a composite key the way to go?